# Templates for code generation not updating parameters from file

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, code-generation, t4

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ assembly name="C:\Users\ic019672\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\PreTemplateLogic\PreTemplateLogic\bin\Debug\ReadfromCSV.dll" #>
<#@ import namespace="PreTemplateLogic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating" #>
<#@ parameter type="System.String" name="Pprty" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace TemplateLogic
{
 public partial class GeneratedClass 
 {
 Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> dataKey = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
    public void GenerateParentContainer(string cntrlName)
       {
                    <#
                    Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> dataKey = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
                    dataKey = PreTemplateLogic.ReadfromCSV.ReadcsvtoDictionary();
                    Dictionary<string, string> dc = dataKey["ObjectName"];
                    string parntKey = "Parent";
                    string nameKey = "Name";
                    string valueKey = "Value";
                    string x = PreTemplateLogic.ObjectRepository.cntrlName;
                    string[] CntrlPrpty = ReadObjectrepository();
                    #>
                        Console.WriteLine("<#= CntrlPrpty[0] #>");  
        }
  }

 }     

 <#+ 
    public string[] ReadObjectrepository()
{
    try 
    {           
            string[] properties;
            string csvPath = ObjectRepository.xmlFile;
            if (File.Exists(ObjectRepository.xmlFile))
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(csvPath)))
            {
                    string line = reader.ReadLine().ToString();
                    properties = line.Split(',');
            }
            return properties;
            }
            return null;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

        throw;
    }
}

 #>
```

Here is what I want to achieve:

1. I need to generate code at runtime.
2. Some parameters for the code are fetched from an external file(which gets updated quite often).
3. On invoking this template, it needs to fetch the parameters from the file and generate the code.

I'm invoking the template externally from another solution using a custom Host. The `ReadcsvtoDictionary` reads some data to the Dictionary `datakey` which is required by the T4 template in runtime.
Now, even though I update the file which is read by `ReadcsvtoDictionary` and invoke the template again, I do not get the `texttemplate` to get new data..

Comment: What is the problem your trying to solve here? ignoring your attempt at a solution to the problem and it's issues.

Comment: Here is what I want to achieve.. 1. I need to generate code at runtime. 2. Some parameters for the code are fetched from an external file(which gets updated quite often). 3. On invoking this template, it needs to fetch the parameters from the file and generate the code.

Comment: Any help please ??

Answer (score 0):

You can write your ReadObjectrepository method in partial class for this template.

Why you didn't pass ReadObjectrepository() result to template code in template constructor for example?

Constructor can be also in partial class.

In this way debugging will be simplest.